# How does seccomp-bpf filter syscalls?

Tags: linux, security, kernel, system-calls, seccomp

I'm investigating the implementation detail of seccomp-bpf, the syscall filtration mechanism that was introduced into Linux since version 3.5.
I looked into the source code of kernel/seccomp.c from Linux 3.10 and want to ask some questions about it.

From seccomp.c, it seems that seccomp_run_filters() is called from __secure_computing() to test the syscall called by the current process.
But looking into seccomp_run_filters(), the syscall number that is passed as an argument is not used anywhere.

It seems that sk_run_filter() is the implementation of BPF filter machine, but sk_run_filter() is called from seccomp_run_filters() with the first argument (the buffer to run the filter on) NULL.

My question is: how can seccomp_run_filters() filter syscalls without using the argument?

The following is the source code of seccomp_run_filters():

```
/**
 * seccomp_run_filters - evaluates all seccomp filters against @syscall
 * @syscall: number of the current system call
 *
 * Returns valid seccomp BPF response codes.
 */
static u32 seccomp_run_filters(int syscall)
{
        struct seccomp_filter *f;
        u32 ret = SECCOMP_RET_ALLOW;

        /* Ensure unexpected behavior doesn't result in failing open. */
        if (WARN_ON(current->seccomp.filter == NULL))
                return SECCOMP_RET_KILL;

        /*
         * All filters in the list are evaluated and the lowest BPF return
         * value always takes priority (ignoring the DATA).
         */
        for (f = current->seccomp.filter; f; f = f->prev) {
                u32 cur_ret = sk_run_filter(NULL, f->insns);
                if ((cur_ret & SECCOMP_RET_ACTION) < (ret & SECCOMP_RET_ACTION))
                        ret = cur_ret;
        }
        return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user process enters the kernel, the register set is stored to a kernel variable.
The function `sk_run_filter` implements the interpreter for the filter language. The relevant instruction for seccomp filters is `BPF_S_ANC_SECCOMP_LD_W`. Each instruction has a constant `k`, and in this case it specifies the index of the word to be read.

```
#ifdef CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER
            case BPF_S_ANC_SECCOMP_LD_W:
                    A = seccomp_bpf_load(fentry->k);
                    continue;
#endif
```

The function `seccomp_bpf_load` uses the current register set of the user thread to determine the system call information.

Comment: Thanks, Juho. I have understood how the instruction BPF_S_ANC_SECCOMP_LD_W is used to tell the interpreter to load syscall information from struct seccomp_dara.